# Algorithm suggestion

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for the best way to accomplish the following tasks:

Given 4 non-repeatable numbers between 1 and 9.
Given 2 numbers between 1 and 6.

Adding up the two numbers (1 to 6), check to see if there is a way make that same number using the four non-repeatable numbers (1 to 9), plus you may not even have to use all four numbers.

*Example:*
Your four non-repeatable (1 to 9) numbers are: 2, 4, 6, and 7
Your two numbers between 1 and 6 are: 3 and 3

The total for the two numbers is 3 + 3 = 6.

Looking at the four non-repeatable (1 to 9) numbers, you can make a 6 in two different ways:
2 + 4 = 6
6 = 6

So, this example returns "yes, there is a possible solution".

How do I accomplish this task in the most efficient, cleanest way possible, algorithmic-ally.

Comment: This smells like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are only 16 possible combinations of the 4 numbers; why not simply loop over all combinations, and test each?

Comment: this is subset sum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: It's not homework at all, I'm working on a small game called Shut The Box and I am at this part where I gotta determine that there are no more options/moves left, thus game over.  I came here hoping someone may give me the best way to do this.

Comment: Just do it, test it, and if you encounter problems (e.g. code not working or code is too slow), ask again. If you want to get your code reviewed maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ can help!

Comment: I'm not looking for any code, I'm just looking for a general suggestion to accomplish my task.  I cannot code until I have an idea of how I want to do it.  I'm just going to drop this as I'm being downvoted (don't want to be banned from this) and being criticized because my question sounded too "homeworky".

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereSince the number of elements here is 4 so we should not worry about efficiency.
Just loop over 0 to 15 and use it as a bit mask to check what are the valid results that can be generated.
Here is a code in python to give you idea.

```
a = [2,4,6,7]
for i in range(16):
    x = i
    ans = 0
    for j in range(4):
        if(x%2):
            ans += a[j]
        x /= 2
    print ans,
```

> > 0 2 4 6 6 8 10 12 7 9 11 13 13 15 17 19